# New To R with questions about summarize and its output

Tags: r, group-by, summary

I am analyzing how accurate a magnitude estimate is for a star that has a known magnitude (a "standard star"). The accuracy measure is "o.k," which is simply the difference between the observed magnitude and the "known" standard magnitude using a single or multiple standard comparison stars (differential photometry techniques). I compare accuracy if I use a single comparison star, 2 comparison stars, and up to 10 comparison stars. Perfect accuracy would be o.k = 0.000.
The question is: does accuracy increase with an increasing number of comparison stars?
No problem computing the o.k means and standard deviations, using group_by and summarize.

#m67_ntr_122 is a tribble containing all data for the star 122.
n_comp is the number of comparison stars using in a particular treatment.
o.k is the value mentioned above.
ntr_meanOk is the tribble that holds the results.

```
ntr_meanOk <- m67_ntr_122%>%
    group_by(n_comp) %>%
    summarise(
        count = n(),
        mean = mean(o.k),
        sd = sd(o.k)
)
```

But, I am having trouble understanding the results. an example below of the first three rows of the output (1-3 and a "duplicate" set of three rows labeled C01-C03. But, not exactly, the means and standard deviations do differ.

```
 n_comp              o.k mean   o.k SD
 <chr>     <int>       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1          4        0.04675    0.0041130
 2          4        0.02       0.0066833
 3          4        0.0125     0.0061373
 C01        9        0.044444   0.0088898
 C02        9        0.019222   0.0076449
 C03        9        0.013222   0.0072246}
```

Questions

1. Why two sets of values? There is no "C01" in my master tibble.
2. What does the "" column mean in this context? It obviously comes from count = n(). Are the means and SDs calculated on the basis of n=4 in one case and n = 9 in the other?
3. I note that "n_comp" is treated as a character vector not an integer variable. I wonder why and how this might effect the  values.

Here is the requested dput of the master data frame

```
enter dput(head(m67_data))
structure(list(fov = c("M67", "M67", "M67", "M67", "M67", 
"M67"), image_n = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), n_target = c("T10", 
"T10", "T10", "T10", "T10", "T10"), n_comp = c("1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), trans_st = c("NTR", "NTR", "NTR", "NTR", 
 "NTR", "NTR"), filter_image = c("V01", "V01", "V01", "V01", 
 "V01", "V01"), target = c("100", "102", "104_1", "107", 
 "109", "112"), obs_mag = c(10.006, 10.284, 10.484, 10.774, 
  10.949, 11.275), obs_err = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
  0.003, 0.003), t_stdev = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
  0.003, 0.003), t_err_snr = c(0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 
  0.002, 0.002), T_snr = c(880, 771, 704, 615, 560, 478), 
  t_b.v = c(-0.062, 1.264, 0.575, 1.135, 0.096, 0.128), 
  t_std_mag = c(10.04, 10.289, 10.489, 10.763, 10.946, 
  11.263), t_std = c(0.029, 0.016, 0.013, 0.016, 0.019, 0.016
  ), o.k = c(-0.034, -0.005, -0.005, 0.011, 0.003, 0.012), 
  ok.abs = c(0.034, 0.005, 0.005, 0.011, 0.003, 0.012)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
  "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Mind sharing a `dput(head(df))` of your master tibble?

Comment: I added it to the original post, thanks. Ed

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my speculations as well as my replication of your code. C01, C02, and C03 must be somewhere inside of your n_comp column. It parses as character because of that, most likely. You can either find them manually and remove them with something like

`filter(m67_ntr_122, stringr::str_detect(n_comp, "[:alpha:]"))`

or try for

`m67_ntr_122 <- mutate(m67_ntr_122, n_comp = as.integer(stringr::str_extract(n_comp, "\\d+")))`

The blank column is most likely because you chose to name the summary columns after R functions, which you should avoid.

```r
m67_ntr_122 <- structure(list(fov = c("M67", "M67", "M67", "M67", "M67", 
"M67"), image_n = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), n_target = c("T10", 
"T10", "T10", "T10", "T10", "T10"), n_comp = c("1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), trans_st = c("NTR", "NTR", "NTR", "NTR", 
 "NTR", "NTR"), filter_image = c("V01", "V01", "V01", "V01", 
 "V01", "V01"), target = c("100", "102", "104_1", "107", 
 "109", "112"), obs_mag = c(10.006, 10.284, 10.484, 10.774, 
  10.949, 11.275), obs_err = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
  0.003, 0.003), t_stdev = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
  0.003, 0.003), t_err_snr = c(0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 
  0.002, 0.002), T_snr = c(880, 771, 704, 615, 560, 478), 
  t_b.v = c(-0.062, 1.264, 0.575, 1.135, 0.096, 0.128), 
  t_std_mag = c(10.04, 10.289, 10.489, 10.763, 10.946, 
  11.263), t_std = c(0.029, 0.016, 0.013, 0.016, 0.019, 0.016
  ), o.k = c(-0.034, -0.005, -0.005, 0.011, 0.003, 0.012), 
  ok.abs = c(0.034, 0.005, 0.005, 0.011, 0.003, 0.012)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
  "data.frame")) %>%
  mutate(n_comp = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))

ntr_meanOk <- m67_ntr_122%>%
    group_by(n_comp) %>%
    summarise(
        count1 = n(),
        mean1 = mean(o.k),
        sd1 = sd(o.k)
)

# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   n_comp count1   mean1     sd1
#    <int>  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1      1      2 -0.0195 0.0205 
# 2      2      2  0.003  0.0113 
# 3      3      2  0.0075 0.00636
```

Comment: dcsuka: You are correct on all your comments. Stupid of me to forget about naming. And, yes there were some C01, etc. down at the bottom of my 2,800+ rows of data. Its fun to learn R and great that I can find expert help. Many thanks!

Comment: Of course! It's a very nice statistics language. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Also, there is an upvote button and green check mark if this helped you.